# Include(..) statement ignored as soon as Projections used

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a method where **(artist and genre)** throws null reference exception, when i use select clause. if i don't use select clause then it can't convert **system.collections.generic.list to system.collections.generic.ienumerable**.

```
 public ActionResult Attending()
 {
    var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    var gigs = _context.Attendances.Include(a => a.Gig.Artist).Include(a => a.Gig.Genre).Where(a => a.AttendeeId == userId).ToList();
    var viewModel = new GigsViewModel()
    {
       UpcomingGigs = gigs,
       ShowActions = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated,
       Heading = "Gigs I'm Attending"
       };
       return View("Gigs", viewModel);
    }
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class GigsViewModel
{
   public IEnumerable<Gig> UpcomingGigs { get; set; }
   public bool ShowActions { get; set; }
   public string Heading { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Attendance class

```
public class Attendance
{
    public Gig Gig { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Attendee { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int GigId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string AttendeeId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: At what line is the exception thrown?

Comment: This line .......var gigs = _context.Attendances.Where(a => a.AttendeeId == userId).Select(a => a.Gig).Include(g=>g.Artist).Include(g=>g.Genre).ToList();

Comment: That this line `User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value` because the part `User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)` that throws an exception is `null`and you're calling `.Value` on it.

Comment: No.....userId not throwing exception.....

Comment: So only authenticated users can reach this code?

Comment: yes only authenticated user

Comment: How to convert list to ienumerable???

Comment: What type is `_context.Attendances`?

Comment: ICollection type

Comment: public ICollection<Attendance> Attendances { get; set; }  check update in my code

Comment: So how would you assign that to an `IEnumerable<Gig>`?